# git how to merge an old featurebranch?

Tags: git

I am looking at merging an older featurebranch back into master. The feature is basically way behind in commits to the master so has a lot of potential conflicts when merging back. I could just open 2 editors and manually pick the changes into master. Not familiar with git enough to know whether there are ways in git to manage this. So to clarify in a sample when I branched off the feature the master looked like this:

```
A-B-C
```

Now my feature looks like this:

```
A-B-C-F-G-H-K
```

and the master:

```
A-B-C-D-E-L-M-N
```

So looks like the master has changed quite a bit(should have merged more often I guess). 
Is there a way with git so I can easily merge/apply the F,G,H,K commits back into master after N?

Comment: What I do in these cases, is rebase my feature branch against latest master, resolving conflicts in the process. Then the feature branch is safe to be merged. (actually, I do this _every_ time I merge a branch).

Comment: "Is there a way with git so I can easily merge/apply the F,G,H,K commits back into master after N?" - yes, [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: I actually tried this same scenario using git rebase but kept on getting conflicts/ resolving conflicts/ conflicts resolved and getting conflicts again? Ok I haven’t described the exact situation for this but does this sound familiar?

Comment: Well yes, you reapply commits one by one. Each next can cause new conflicts. You just have to persevere. :) to reduce the pain, you may squash new commits in your feature branch, so that there's only one.

Comment: This is also a reason why you shouldn't have long-running feature branches.

Comment: Yeah I know feeling the pain now

Comment: There is no way round the fact that you'll need to resolve conflicts.  Rebasing is not a magic bullet here, and often it can be even more painful, as you may need to resolve conflicts N times.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily true that there are merge conflicts. You'll know when creating a pull request into master. Depending on the kind of work you've done, there may not be appreciable risk of issues.

There are several ways of getting the new commits from master into your branch.

1. You can merge master into your feature branch. It's simple and most people do that, but it is not the preferred option unless you always squash merge into master, because it makes the history unnecessarily messy.
2. You can `git rebase --onto master C` from the feature branch. This will work, but you can get into a supremely frustrating situation where every commit has its own individual conflicts, even if the net change is minimal. The more commits you have the worse this gets.
3. You can first squash your changes with `git rebase -i C` then `git rebase --onto master C`. This provides the advantage of rebasing, but with only one commit to rebase the process is a lot quicker.
4. You can perform a squash merge into master, then set your feature branch to that.

   ```
   git checkout origin/master // checks out master as detached head
   git merge --squash mybranch // merge mybranch as one squashed commit
   git checkout -B mybranch // sets feature to the detached head and checkout
   ```

   This method has the advantage of avoiding the rather manual process of squashing commits with rebase. If there are no conflicts, it only takes a few seconds, and it takes place safely on a detached head, so you don't change your branch until you're satisfied.

If you only have a few commits, option 2 is ideal. As you have progressively more commits and more conflicts to deal with, options 3 and then 4 are more straightforward. Also, options 1 and 4 are the only ones able to easily work when there are merge commits in your history.

Comment: Thanks let me try those options

Comment: "but it is not the preferred option unless you always squash merge into master, because it makes the history unnecessarily messy" - I strongly disagree with this: When you merge, you record the history as it happened, when you squash-merge, or rebase, you are recording a lie. And that lie has consequences. Namely, it will make `git bisect` much less useful. `git` is designed for concurrent merging in all directions, because that is how development happens. It's only the brains of some developers and some inadequate tools like `svn` that call for linear history.

Comment: It’s an argument of preference so there’s no right answer. However, as someone who regularly traverses Git logs trying to resolve issues, I much prefer a practical and readable history over a pure one. Knowing a developer added five logs for white space fixes or “WIP” spam is not useful history. Likewise merges from master serve no useful historical purpose. A perfect world for me is one where every feature branch by a single dev has a single commit. But again this is largely a discussion of opinions that probably doesn’t have a place here

Comment: Do you ever use `git bisect`?

Comment: Nope when would this be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer rebasing branches rather than merging branches, because the commit history looks cleaner without excessive merge commits.

Assuming that your feature branch is a private branch (rebasing shared branches is generally not a good idea), what I would to is therefore to rebase the branch. In your example this would yield the commit history `A-B-C-D-E-L-M-N-F'-G'-H'-K'`:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

However, *before* you do that, you could enable the "git rerere" feature (**re**member **re**corded **re**solution).

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

This feature can make git recognize repeated similar merge conflict scenarios, and automatically apply previous merge conflict resolutions.
I.e. you would have to resolve a merge conflict once, but the second time a similar merge conflict is discovered, your previous resolution will be applied automatically. You should still review that the automated resolution looks okay, and run a suite of automated tests, if available, when the rebase is finished.

Before you start using `git rerere`, I would recommend you read through the [git rerere documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere).

Comment: I tried this but did not work for me, like said it keeps on coming with conflicts

Answer (score 0):

You have four options here:

1. **You just merge.** Have you actually tried it? If you haven't, do so, you can still abort the process if you figure that you don't get the hang of the conflicts.

   That said, I strongly prefer setting

   ```
   git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
   ```

   so that I always see the base version along with the two conflicting changes in the conflict markers that `git` produces. This is a huge help when sorting out merge conflicts.
2. **You merge incrementally.** If 1. does not work out because basically everything conflicts with everything, it might be necessary to split the merging into several stages. Look at the history of master, find a suitable chunk of development (some old commit between your branch-off point and your current `master`), and merge that into your feature branch. Unless you try to merge too much at a time, the merge should be relatively easy. Rinse and repeat until you have successfully merged your current `master` commit into your feature branch. After that, you can simply fast forward your master to the merge.
3. **You rebase your feature branch.** An alternative to 2. is to rebase your feature branch onto the current master. This will force you to merge each individual feature commit with the entire `master` development, but at least, you only have to worry about a single feature branch commit at a time. As an added bonus, this allows you to provide a "clean" history, where all your feature commits appear one after the other without any merges.

   Beware, this will create **new** commits in place of the original ones. Make sure to test all of them as it is relatively easy to create nonsensical commits with a rebase.
4. **You incrementally rebase your feature branch.** If your merge conflicts are still too heavy with approach 3., you may combine it with approach 2.: Repeatedly rebase the feature branch onto newer and newer commits in the history of `master`. This is tedious, but it may be the canon that's needed to do the job. Just make sure to try the less tedious approaches first.